# How does Hierarchical Pathfinding deal with obstructions in the same chunk?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, rts

[Aigamedev.com](http://aigamedev.com/open/review/near-optimal-hierarchical-pathfinding/) provides this visualization of HPA*:

[image: aigamedev visualization]

All the nodes within the same chunk connect to each other. What if there was an obstruction between nodes in the same chunk? For example:

[image: obustruction in center bottom left chunk]

What would the resulting visualization look like with an obstruction in the center bottom left chunk? How would this be detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning the chunk into two might result in additional entrances (nodes) in the graph, but otherwise there is nothing special that happens.  Your statement *"all the nodes within the same chunk [must] connect to each other"* is false.

In your example the resulting entrances are the same *(only a few edges are removed from the graph)*, but in [the paper](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~mmueller/ps/hpastar.pdf) the authors give an example where a partition causes the sides of one chunk to be split into multiple entrances.

[image: Multiple entrances]

Comment: To detect these obstructions and prevent the connection from being generated, do I need to pathfind within the cluster between all the entrances?

Comment: @JPtheK9 Yes, that is a required part of the algorithm in order to determine the distance between entrances.